# What is the best way to reformat this piece of SQL to avoid the thousands separator

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of a SQL stored procedure (producing XML output) I have the following line:

```
FORMAT(Quantity * ld.UnitPrice, 'N2') AS '@value'
```

This has produced perfectly acceptable results for several months now. Last week however the service into which the XML that this procedure produces failed because the value was over a thousand pounds (sterling), producing the following output `1,049.60`.

It would have been nice had the service documentation mentioned the fact that it didn't like commas in the values passed back to it as attributes but that argument is for another day.

I'm after some advice as to the best way to reformat this one line so that it does not produce anything that separates thousands, in other words I need it to produce the following `1049.60` or something similar whenever a value over one thousand pounds is arrived at. It still needs to retain the two decimal places.

Although I have mentioned specifically Pounds sterling in truth this format needs to be culture neutral, so that all figures that rise above a thousand do not have a separator.

Comment: Remove the format function? Then if required convert(decimal(9,2), YourColumn)

Comment: Thank you, works nicely.  Perfect solution.

Comment: @SeanLange . . . Could you please add your comment as an answer so Dom can accept it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably remove the format function. Then if required add `convert(decimal(9,2), YourColumn)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FORMAT function with format of 'F2'. 'F' is the Fixed-Point format specifier. This is supported by all numeric types.

```
DECLARE @quantity int = 65;
DECLARE @unitPrice money = 150.33;

SELECT FORMAT(@quantity * @unitPrice, 'F2') AS 'Amount';
```

[image]

See Books Online > FORMAT (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx

MSDN > Standard Numeric Format Strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

However, if you are formatting numbers as strings and then passing them around, you need to be careful about language and culture settings. The decimal separator has the potential to change to a comma.

You could ensure this is always a full-stop, by specifying the culture as 'en-US' to the FORMAT function, which takes an optional third parameter.

```
SET LANGUAGE 'Portuguese';
SELECT FORMAT(@quantity * @unitPrice, 'F2', 'en-US') AS 'Amount';
```

[image]

See Defensive Database Programming with SQL Server by Alex Kuznetsov, published by Redgate > Chapter 1: Basic Defensive Database Programming Techniques > How SET LANGUAGE can break a query

> Many developers test their code only under the default language setting of their server, and do not test how their code will respond if executed on a server with a different language setting, or if there is a change in the setting at the session level.

Books Online > Local Language Versions in SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210665.aspx#BK_ConfigureOS

Comment: Plus one rep just for mentioning Alex Kuznetsov's excellent book. Gold!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share an option if you decide to stick to `format` function, it supports other formats as well:

```
FORMAT(Quantity * ld.UnitPrice, '0.00') AS '@value'
```